# Semantic UI React: Make Table have height of container

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have a `<Table>` inside of a `<Grid>`. The grid's spacing works properly. However, the Table doesn't seem to care and overflows:
[image: Table overflowing]
Giving the table a height doesn't seem to affect it at all.

I want the Table to never go out of the space allotted to it by the Grid. If the table is too big, the Table.Body should scroll.

I'm using Semantic UI React.

Here's my current code:

```
<Grid style={{"height": "90vh"}}>
  <Grid.Row style={{"height": "50%"}}>
    <Grid.Column width={8}>
      <Table striped style={{"height": "500px", "overflow": "scroll"}}>
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell style={{"fontSize": "32px", "textAlign": "center"}}>TABLE 1</Table.HeaderCell>
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>
        <Table.Body style={{"overflow": "scroll"}}>
          <Table.Row>
            <Table.Cell>
              <p style={{"fontSize": "25px", "display": "inline"}}>There would be more of me, but for simplicity's sake it's just me!</p>
            </Table.Cell>
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Body>
      </Table>
    </Grid.Column>
    <Grid.Column width={8}>
      (another table would go here. This is the table that blocks table 1 in the picture above)
    </Grid.Column>
  </Grid.Row>

  <Grid.Row style={{"height": "50%"}}>
    <Grid.Column width={8}>
      (another table would go here)
    </Grid.Column>
    <Grid.Column width={8}>
      (another table would go here)
    </Grid.Column>
  </Grid.Row>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Tables can't be easily styled with CSS no matter what framework or flavor-of-the-month-js you use. If the data inside is not tabular data conciser taking your data out of a table. But please leave it inside a table if it is indeed tabular data.

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle if possible, would be easier to debug.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the table in a div and setting the height and overflow styles on that?

Comment: I ended up following @Dominik 's advice and I am using a list now.